# Crashing after Button click trying to Insert in SQLite (Code and Stacktrace)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, insert, android-studio

Hi again i need help in Insert a data in SQLite, when i click the button my app it's crashed...

someone can check it?

**SavacDataBaseAdapter.java:**

```
package com.example.yiquishum.savac4k;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SavacDataBaseAdapter {

    SavacDBHelper helper;

    public SavacDataBaseAdapter(Context context){
        helper = new SavacDBHelper(context);
    }

    public long InsertData(String name, String username, String pass, String gen, String state){

        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(SavacDBHelper.FName, name);
        contentValues.put(SavacDBHelper.Fnameuser, username);
        contentValues.put(SavacDBHelper.FPass, pass);
        contentValues.put(SavacDBHelper.Fgen, gen);
        contentValues.put(SavacDBHelper.Fstate, state);

        long id = db.insert(SavacDBHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        return id;

    }

    static class SavacDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String TAG = "BD Savac";

        static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Savac4K";
        static final String TABLE_NAME = "SavacUser";
        static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    /* Aqui iran las variables que van en el Query */

        static final String FIDuser = "_Id";
        static final String FName = "Nombre";
        static final String Fnameuser = "Usuario";
        static final String FPass = "Contra";
        static final String Fgen = "Gen";
        static final String Fstate = "Estado";

        /**
         * ******************************************
         */

    /* Aqui iran los Querys de la Base de Datos */

        static final String Query1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + FIDuser + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + FName + " VARCHAR(255), " + Fnameuser + " F VARCHAR(255), " + FPass + " VARCHAR(255), " + Fgen + " INTEGER, " + Fstate + " VARCHAR(255));";
        static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TABLE_NAME;

        /**
         * *****************************************
         */

        public SavacDBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Entro a la BD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.v(TAG, "Entro a la BD");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            //Crear la Base de datos osea las Tablas

            db.execSQL(Query1);
            Log.v(TAG, "Se crea la BD");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }
    }
}
```

**Pregistro.java:**

```
package com.example.yiquishum.savac4k;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Pregistro extends ActionBarActivity {

    SavacDataBaseAdapter SavacDataBaseAdap;
    // Declaracion de las Variables para insertarlas en la BD

    EditText Rname, Rusername, Rpass;
    Spinner Rgen, Rstate;

    private static final String TAG = "Registro";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pregistro);

        Spinner state = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.estado);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.estado,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        state.setAdapter(adapter);

        Spinner sex = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.genero);
        ArrayAdapter adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.xexo,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sex.setAdapter(adapter2);

        SavacDataBaseAdap = new SavacDataBaseAdapter(this);

        /* Aquí obtenemos los datos por vía ID */
        Rname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        Rusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Usuario);
        Rpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
        Rgen = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.genero);
        Rstate = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.estado);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pregistro, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id){
            case R.id.cancelar:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Regresando a la pantalla de Inicio ='(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                Log.v(TAG, "Cancelada el Registro");
                return true;
            default:
                return onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void Registrar(View view){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Gracias por Registrarte", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        Log.v(TAG, "Se ha registrado satisfactoriamente");


        //Aqui obtendremos los datos para insertarlo en la BD

        String Ename = Rname.getText().toString();
        String Euser = Rusername.getText().toString();
        String Epass = Rpass.getText().toString();
        String Egen = Rgen.getOnItemSelectedListener().toString();
        String Esta = Rstate.getOnItemSelectedListener().toString();

        long id = SavacDataBaseAdap.InsertData(Ename, Euser, Epass, Egen, Esta);

        if (id < 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo registrar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.v(TAG, "No se pudo Resigtrar el Usuario");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bienvenido " +Euser, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.v(TAG, "Se pudo registrar el Usuario");
        }
    }
}
```

**XML Pregistro:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.yiquishum.savac4k.Pregistro">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/nombre"
    android:hint="Nombre"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Usuario"
    android:hint="Nombre de Usuario"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nombre"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/pass"
    android:hint="@string/pass"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Usuario"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Usuario"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Usuario"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/genero"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pass" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/estado"
    android:layout_below="@+id/genero"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/genero" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Registrar"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/estado"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:onClick="Registrar"/>
```

**Stacktrace**

```
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838): Process: com.example.yiquishum.savac4k, PID: 19838
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    ... 11 more
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    at com.example.yiquishum.savac4k.Pregistro.Registrar(Pregistro.java:92)
08-19 15:08:09.597: E/AndroidRuntime(19838):    ... 14 more
```

If you need more information they tell me, thanks guys :)

Comment: NPE in Pregistro.java:92 - what's there?

Comment: in (Pregistro.java:92): String Egen = Rgen.getOnItemSelectedListener().toString(); is a Spinner

Comment: and what is that?  + Fnameuser + " F VARCHAR(255), " +

Comment: ohhh..... let me check it

Comment: Yeah is a Typing error in my Query thanks everybody :D!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you have a NPE when trying to retrieve Rgen.getOnItemSelectedListener(). If you haven't set OnItemSelectedListener, this method will return null which will result in NPE when trying to call toString().

Make sure you set OnItemSelectedListener before trying to retrieve it and use it. You have some examples here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Answer (score 1):

you are getting NPE on `String Egen = Rgen.getOnItemSelectedListener().toString();`
You need to get the spinner value before you access it:
You can get the spinner value by using code like below:

```
Rgen.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Comment: i use this code:

>String Egen = Rgen.getSelectedItem().toString();